# Own method in AppDelegate

Tags: objective-c

Is it possible to declare an own method in App Delegate?
I keep getting an error and I wonder, whether its  because of that.
It says
    expected method body
but it seems to be a proper method body.

```
- (void)checkDefaultSetInt:(NSString *)defaultName (int)newValue {

NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

int valueToCheck = [defaults integerForKey:defaultName];

NSLog(@"%d", valueToCheck);


}
```

Comment: post your code.. anyway is possible add own method in App Delegate

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You method name is incorrect

`- (void)checkDefaultSetInt:(NSString *)defaultName (int)newValue`

Should be something like:

`- (void)checkDefault:(NSString *)defaultName intValue:(int)newValue`

Comment: oh darn, sorry! thanks! got to get used to that syntax

Comment: @user3341702 When someone posts an answer that solves your issue you should accept that answer. It increases your reputation, it increases the answerer's reputation, and it indicates that the question is closed. Do this by clicking the on checkmark next to the answer.

Comment: thanks, I was about to do so but stackexchange told me I couldn't do it.